# Rails update method not saving form data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to go from edit form page to preview page which displays the updated information. Currently, I added `update` method to the `controller` which re-directs (when the form is submitted) to the preview page. But on the preview page, nothing is updated and the data is not saved to the database.

jobs_controller.rb

```
def update 
  @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to preview_path(id: @job.id), notice: 'Job was successfully updated.'
end
```

jobs/preview.html.erb

```
<span class="col-md-12 col-centered">
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_job_path(@job), :class => "jobBack-btn" %>
  <%= link_to "Publish",'#', id:'link_id', class: "btn" %>
</span>
```

If I remove the `update` method, the edit form saves and redirects to `show` page (by default). I have to go to the preview page to see the changes. I'm not sure what I'm missing in the `update` method to save the form data.

Comment: You are probably using some gem that provides a default implementation for the update action. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Your update action does not actually update the `@job` (it just fetches it). I'd expect to see something like `@job.update(params.require('job'))` in that method. (And also you'd want to check the return value of that `@job.update`.)

Comment: @Raffael I don't think I was using a gem that provides a default implementation for update. You were right about the update action not actually updating because it was only fetching the `@job` and not doing anything with it. I updated my code and now it updates and redirects successfully thanks to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried actually updating the object in `update` method?

```
def update 
  @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  if @job.update(update_params)
    redirect_to preview_path(id: @job.id), notice: 'Job was successfully updated.'
  else
    redirect_to somewhere_path, notice: @job.errors.full_messages.join "\n"
  end
end

private

def update_params
  params.require(:job).permit( ... )
end
```

Right now it looks like you're simply finding the job and then redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my code and now it updates and redirects successfully thanks to the comments. I am on a older version of Rails (Rails 4.0.8).

jobs_controller.rb

```
def update 
  @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  if @job.update(params.require('job'))
    redirect_to preview_path(id: @job.id), notice: 'Job was successfully updated.'
  else
    redirect_to '/jobs'
  end
end
```